# Technical details of premining

Tags: mining-theory

I'm just kind of an enthusiastic beginner in this topic. I have created an altcoin using one of the many public available sources (cryptonote in this case). I want now to create a new coin with premine. After I read a lots of comments I still don't get the exact point which would I need to modify in the code to have my coins premined.

What I have in my mind (correct me if I'm wrong): There is a two-step compilation. First is without genesis block, this is actually for generating the genesis block. Second is the final with genesis block included in the config.

So my idea is to include the premined coins' transaction in the genesis block in first run. Is this a good way doing it?

If yes, I assume Currency.cpp needs to be modified. Here is I'm a bit stuck, how can I manually 'mine' 10% of my total coins? Should I modify baseReward to totalcoins * 10% in the first compilation?

Thanks.